# List keys and values from JSON file

Tags: angular, typescript

This is my json:

```
{
  "USD": "United States Dollar",
  "CHF": "Swiss Franc",
  "EUR": "Euro",
  "GBP": "British Pound Sterling"
}
```

And this is my interface:

```js
export interface Currencies {
  currency: string
}
```

I have stored the JSON into `src/assets/currencies.json` and now I would like to list all keys and values.

This is what I have tried:

**currencies.service.ts**

```js
constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }
  
list(): Subscription {
  return this._http.get('./assets/currencies.json').subscribe(data => data);
}
```

**list.component.ts**

```js
getAllCurrencies(): Subscription {
  console.log(this._currencyService.list())
  return this._currencyService.list();
}
```

Well, this is what I get, which is not what I expect:

[image]

What I want is just a simple list of keys and values. E.g.

Keys:

- USD
- CHF
- EUR
- GBP

Values:

- United States Dollar
- Swiss Franc
- Euro
- British Pound Sterling

How can I do this?

Comment: You shouldn't use `.subscribe` in `list` method

Comment: what you have on HTML? can you please add that in question too?

Comment: @PankajParkar I don't have the HTML yet. For now, I am invoking `getAllCurrencies()` in constructor(), just to see if I get the correct data first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
list(): Observable<Currencies> {
  return this._http.get('./assets/currencies.json');
}
```

```js
getAllCurrencies(): Observable<Currencies> {
  return this._currencyService.list();
}
```

```
public currencies$ = this.getAllCurrencies();
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="currencies$ | async as currencies">
  Keys:
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of currencies | keyvalue">
      {{item.key}}
    </li>
  </ul>

  Values:
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of currencies | keyvalue">
      {{item.value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I get this error on the return of `list()`: _TS2322: Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Currencies>'.
  The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
    Property 'currency' is missing in type 'Object' but required in type 'Currencies'._

Comment: Because you have no types in your JSON. Try doing this first: `get(..) as unknown as Observable<Currencies>`.